# Arduino UNO Low-Power Consumption (Multiple Ultra-Sonic Sensors)

Tags: arduino-uno

I've read post that it's possible to connect multiple Ultra-Sonic Sensors to one Arduino.
But I have a few questions:

1. If I use Arduino Uno, what is the maximum number of Ultra Sonic Sensors that I can connect one Arduino UNO?
2. Is there any option to power Arduino UNO in some kind of low-power mode so I can achieve power autonomy for at least 90 days.(I'm referring to battey life, or solar powered solutions)
3. Can Arduino UNO work on the low/high temperatures (e.g. -20 / +50 Celsius degrees), and what is the known work temperature range?
4. How to secure jumpers/cables to work on extreme temperatures (e.g. -20 / +50 Celsius degrees)

   Thanks in advance :D

Comment: A "bare minimum" standalone Arduino will use less power. [useful link](https://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11497)

Comment: 4. Don't use jumper cables. Use cables rates for the specified temperature range and solder them to the board

Comment: @newbie thanks, man. This link is very helpful

Comment: @chrisl Roger that. For the testing purpose, I wanted to use jumpers. :D

Comment: @rmir you're welcome. most electronic components have wide range of temperature tolerance but the real problem is humidity in outdoor environment.

Answer (score 2):

1. You did not specified, what kind of ultrasonic sensor you want to use so I assume use of "standard" ultrasonic Arduino modules (like hc-sr04), which need 4 pin (VCC, GND, TRIGGER and ECHO). Since Arduino Uno has got 20 IO pins (6 analog and 14 digital), you can use 10 pins as outputs for TRIG signals and 10 as inputs for ECHO signals and thus connect up to 10 ultrasonic modules to one Arduino Uno.
2. In general, Arduino Uno is not designed for low-power applications. If you want more specific answer, you should ask more specific question...
3. Working temperature of Arduino Uno is -40 to 85 °C.
4. One of the options is using a terminal shield with screw terminals, e.g something like [this](https://arduino-shop.eu/arduino-platform/1200-arduino-uno-terminal-shield.html).

Comment: Sorry for not being too specific, you know, when you are working on something, you think that everyone has the same process, same tools... And I'm a newbie to Arduino... :D  

1. Yeah, you are right, I was referring to HC-SR04. 
2. Again I wasn't too specific. Didn't want you to bother with too many details, but I need a measurement device that will measure distance every 15 seconds, my plan is to turn on/off Arduino every 15 seconds to measure the distance. Since I need this device to be used in the woods, I need a battery-powered device. 
3. Thanks. 
4. Awesome.

Comment: Look at `sleep_mode()` and `set_sleep_mode(mode)` function. You will also need to switch off the power supply for the ultrasonic sensors. Then you'll need to measure power consumption of the whole set to be able to decide what kind of battery you should use...